# obtain users details after the user logs in to facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have my login button on my website which all works fine. But i would like to get the users email, first and last names and facebook ID and store these in a database, once ive got the details i know how to add these to the database its just getting the information from facebook that's the problem i have permission to access there basic info and send emails i was just wondering how i obtain that information

My login button looks like this

```
script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
           FB.init({ 
            appId:'137558232981530', cookie:true, 
            status:true, xfbml:true 
         });
         $num = 1;
      </script>
      <fb:login-button perms="email, user_about_me, publish_stream">Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

Comment: so you want to get these informations without any previous permission of the user? I don't really think this will work and if so then fb should do something about it! because as far as i know i have to give my permission if any FB APP wants to use any personal information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fb-login-button` code throws an event when it's invoked that you can subscribe to. Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<fb:login-button perms="email,user_about_me,publish_stream"></fb:login-button>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
    FB.init({ 
        appId:'137558232981530', 
        cookie:true, 
        status:true, 
        xfbml:true 
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) 
    {
        // handle the response however you want, response should be a session with user info
        // that you can POST to a server-side script and extract whatever data you need.
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How would i assign say facebookID to a variable that i can post?

Comment: I forget what comes back in response (`console.debug(response)` in your favorite Javascript debugging console should help you learn that) but I think it's something like response.session.uid. So you'd do a `$.post('/wherever/you/want/to/send', { uid: response.session.uid }, function(ajax_response) { //move on });` inside that FB.Event callback. Once you have that data you don't need to use a Facebook method to store it, just use jQuery or querystring parameters or whatever you're comfortable with.